# Getting the following error when running lambda "errorMessage": "Cannot read property 'requestParameters' of undefined",

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to run a lambda to set log retention of log groups in AWS to 14 days, I pulled up the following .js code from the web but when I am running it I am getting an error  `"errorMessage": "Cannot read property 'requestParameters' of undefined",. Runtime of Nodejs is 8.10.`

Here is the .js I am running:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const cloudwatchLogs = new AWS.CloudWatchLogs();

function setRetentionOfCloudwatchLogGroup(logGroupName, duration) {
    let params = {
        logGroupName : logGroupName,
        retentionInDays: duration
    };
    return cloudwatchLogs.putRetentionPolicy(params).promise();
}

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const logGroupName = event.logGroupName ? event.logGroupName : event.detail.requestparameters.logGroupName;
    try {
        await setRetentionOfCloudwatchLogGroup(logGroupName, 14);
        console.log('Retention has been set to ' + logGroupName + 'for 2 weeks');
        return;
    } catch(error) {
        console.error(error);
        throw error;
    }
};
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Response:
{
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "errorMessage": "Cannot read property 'requestParameters' of undefined",
  "trace": [
    "TypeError: Cannot read property 'requestParameters' of undefined",
    "    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:14:81)",
    "    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:63:25)",
    "    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The event’s detail property on line 14 is not being set. Not sure if you expect the event to have that in every call, but I imagine that there are cases when no details need to be passed through the event handler and the property is left empty. A simple null check will fix this.

Comment: Thanks for responding, can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: It’s hard to say exactly when I don’t have all of your code, BUT... I think the way you have set these events up, or the way they are setup in the SDK, they are not returning the details that you are expecting. The check for event.logGroupName where you default to event.details.logGroupName doesn’t seem safe. I would think that they would both be set at the same time, or that one is a computed property for the other. Maybe you’re in an unexpected state